# Query regarding Azure SQL database setup

Tags: azure, database, cloud, microsoft, azure-sql

I am new to Azure and I am required to create a Azure SQL database. So far I have created a Azure SQL server and post that sql database.

Now my main concern comes as to how to access that database? do we really require a virtual machine for that?

Answer (score 1):

While SQL server Management studio is built-in utility for managing SQL 
Express there are alternatives available even as portable applications.

- Microsoft SQL Management Studio
- HeidiSQL
- Toad for SQL Server
- DbForge Studio for SQL Server
- EMS SQL Management Studio for SQL Server
- LINQPad

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by access but to manage the Azure SQL Database you can easily access it with SQL management studio from your laptop (or server).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms

Comment: do we require VM for that or we can download SQL management studio on local and connect it?
another way I was thinking is to RDP to server and install the applications there and then run it, is it viable?

Comment: You can download and install SQL management studio on your client/computer. It’s described in the link I posted. You can’t RDP to the Azure SQL server since it’s a PaaS service